# Can DataGrid.Resources be set in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, code-behind

I want to change WPF DataGrid's brush color in code behind.
This is working XAML code:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Is it possible to set this XAML code in codebehind (in constructor of custom class inherited from default DataGrid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this (if you are using a custom class):

```
  public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
  {
    public CustomDataGrid()
    {
      var converter = new BrushConverter(); 
      var background = FindResource(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey); 
      var foreground = FindResource(SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey);
      this.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBr‌​ushKey, (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(background.ToString())); 
      this.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTe‌​xtBrushKey, (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(foreground.ToString())); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code gave me Unhandled exception: System.InvalidCastException: Object of type System.Windows.Media.Color cannot be retyped to System.Windows.Media.Brush.

Comment: Solved by:

var converter = new BrushConverter();
            var background = FindResource(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey);
            var foreground = FindResource(SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey);

            this.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey, (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(background.ToString()));
            this.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey, (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(foreground.ToString()));

Comment: @Bugscz Sorry for the error. I'll correct the answer. However is this approach working?

Answer (score 1):

Daniele Sartori:

Thank you so much. Your answer is solution for my problem but gives exceptions. Problem solved by this code:

```
var converter = new BrushConverter();
var background = FindResource(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey);
var foreground = FindResource(SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey);

this.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey, (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(background.ToString()));
this.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey, (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(foreground.ToString()));
```